# background-attachement:fixed issue on ios

Tags: ios, css, background, background-image

The background image is hidden on ios when i put:

```
background-attachement:fixed
```

Do you know a fix for this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: It's `background-attachment: fixed;`, without the *e*.

Comment: Yes I'm a frenchman. French doesn't speak  or write good english?

Answer (score 0):

Just because Attachement do not exist.

The correct is `background-attachment: fixed;`.